# How do I correctly define rewrite rule?

Tags: nginx

I have a docker with a lizmap that respond in local to the address http://192.168.1.85:8090
I have a nginx that proxy https://geoservizi.pippoepluto.net/ to previous internal url.

I would like to modify https://geoservizi.pippoepluto.net/ -> https://geoservizi.pippoepluto.net/webgis and proxy always to http://192.168.1.85:8090

The problem is that I have to add /webgis/ to all urls to local machine and I do not find the way...

Thanks in advance..

My vhost block:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.85:8090;
}
```

Comment: Change the location to `location /webgis/` and the proxy_pass to `proxy_pass http://192.168.1.85:8090/;`

Comment: Thanks Richard! With this block I lose urls! I need to automatically insert /webgis/ in all the urls. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve, maybe you want the opposite: `location / { ... proxy_pass http://192.168.1.85:8090/webgis/; }`